# select max value in a group of consecutive values

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

How do you do to retrieve only the max value of a group with only consecutive values?

I have a telephone database with only unique values and I want to get only the highest number of each telephone number group TelNr and I am struggling.

```
id     |      TeNr       |      Position
1      |      100        |     SLMO2.1.3
2      |      101        |     SLMO2.3.4
3      |      103        |     SLMO2.4.1
4      |      104        |     SLMO2.3.2
5      |      200        |     SLMO2.5.1
6      |      201        |     SLMO2.5.2
7      |      204        |     SLMO2.5.5
8      |      300        |     SLMO2.3.5
9      |      301        |     SLMO2.6.2
10     |      401        |     SLMO2.4.8
```

Result should be:

```
TelNr
101
104
201
204
301
401
```

I have tried almost every tip I could find so far and whether I get all TelNr or no number at all which is useless in my case.

Any brilliant idea to run this with SQLITE?

Comment: It's not clear. How do you group ? Why there is no 100 in result outpu?

Comment: Because I want to get the last highest value to be able to choose the next one. For example, in this case, TelNr are 100 to 199, 200 to 299, 300 to 399 and so on. sometimes numbers are missing, so I could use them.

100 is not present as 101 is the first highest number found within 100 range as 102 is missing :)

Answer (score 1):

So you're searching for gaps and want to get the first value of those gaps.

This is probably the best way to get them, try to check for a row with the current TeNr plus 1 and if there's none you found it:

```
select t1.TeNr, t1.TeNr + 1 as unused_TeNr
from tab as t1
left join Tab as t2
on t2.TeNr = t1.TeNr + 1
where t2.TeNr is null
```

**Edit:**

To get the range of missing values you need to use some old-style SQL as SQLite doesn't seem to support ROW_NUMBER, etc.

```
select
   TeNr + 1 as RangeStart, 
   nextTeNr - 1 as RangeEnd, 
   nextTeNr - TeNr - 1 as cnt
from
 (
   select TeNr, 
     ( select min(TeNr) from tab as t2
       where t2.TeNr > t1.TeNr ) as nextTeNr
   from tab as t1
 ) as dt
where nextTeNr > TeNr + 1
```

It's probably not very efficient, but might be ok if the number of rows is small and/or there's a index on TeNr.

Getting each value in the gap as a row in your result set is very hard, if your version of SQLite supports recursive queries:

```
with recursive cte (TeNr, missing, maxTeNr) as
 (
   select
      min(TeNr) as TeNr,   -- start of range of existing numbers
      0 as missing,        -- 0 = TeNr exists, 1 = TeNr is missing
      max(TeNr) as maxTeNr -- end of range of existing numbers
   from tab 

   union all

   select
      cte.TeNr + 1,        -- next TeNr, if it doesn't exists tab.TeNr will be NULL
      case when tab.TeNr is not null then 0 else 1 end, 
      maxTeNr
   from cte left join tab
   on tab.TeNr = cte.TeNr + 1
   where cte.TeNr + 1 < maxTeNr
  )  
select TeNr 
from cte
where missing = 1
```

Depending on your data this might return a huge amount of rows.
You might also use the result of the previous RangeStart/RangeEnd query as input to this recursion.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! It works straight away. 
A big thank you dnoeth, you saved me some white nights!
May I ask how we could possibly get all the values in the gaps?

Comment: @user3808023: Everything is possible in SQL :-) But it might result in bad performance :-( Edited my answer